# Is it safe to stay in Kowloon in Hong Kong this week?

Tags: safety, hong-kong, event-based-effects

I am staying a day in Hong Kong on Thursday/Friday on my way to Australia. Is it safe? What are necessary precautions? Should I stay in the airport all this time?

Comment: To the close voters: I have no idea why the questions attracted two "opinion based" close votes. Kowloon is objectively safe, just look at the statistics.

Comment: IMO it's much nicer to stay Central side - so do that!  :)  Both are perfectly safe.

Comment: There has been a major police action going on over the last 24 hours or so. So I'm not sure that anyone can really say anything reliable about this right now. Last week's experience doesn't necessarily apply today. The police have put out an announcement threatening to use live ammunition.

Comment: @BenCrowell I believe it's mostly targeting universities, so that's probably areas to avoid.

Comment: In a word of caution, it might not be so safe if you are of East Asian origin.

Answer (score 14):

It is safe. Demonstrations mostly occur on the weekends, are quite localized, are mostly peaceful and don't target tourists. If you are paranoid, avoid wearing black clothes, since that's one of the way protesters identify themselves (my French contacts advised me to wear a [yellow vest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_vests_movement) to make sure I'm not mistaken for a protester). I have seen a few protests on the axis Tsim Sha Tsui -> Jordan -> Yau Ma Tei -> Mongkok, but again it's quite peaceful and violence, if any, is directed toward [objects](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/149181/1810) and police, so unless you're one of them, you're fine. The main impact on tourists is [the early closing time of the MTR and Airport Express](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/148861/1810).

Source: I was in Kowloon two weeks ago.

Also, see https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories/hong-kong-travel-advisory.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191120121655/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories/hong-kong-travel-advisory.html)):

> Hong Kong - Level 2: Exercise Increased Caution

You can see the many countries with that level on https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories.html; for example Belgium and France are level 2 as well.

Answer (score 7):

It's perfectly safe.

I've been there a few weeks ago, and the only inconvenience I encountered were unpredictable MTR station and system closures, but in case that happens there are always alternatives (buses, taxis and ultimately walking). The [Citymapper](https://citymapper.com/hong-kong) and [MTR](http://www.mtr.com.hk/en/customer/services/mtr_mobile.html) apps are useful as they provide notifications of closures in real time, and alternative routes as needed.

Protests can happen in unpredictable and unanounced places. If you see groups of either protesters or police, try to find a different route to your destination (basically duck into a side street). Avoid wearing black, as that is the color of the protestors. Protests normally escalate on the weekends, but that is not a firm rule.

[HK Map Live](https://hkmap.live/) site shows the locations of the (some) police and protests almost in real time. It's in Chinese, but you can figure out the areas to avoid based on the icons.

Allow more time than usual for worst-case scenarios if you have to reach a specific place (e.g. catching a flight back).